# is the sandbox broken - 500 error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

is the sandbox for Paypal broken ? I receive a 500 error.

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/websc&cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-78048295RW8002111
```

I wasnt sure if it needs cgi-bin in the url but that does not work either

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/websc&cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-78048295RW8002111
```

It's from my prestashop plugin - which seems to be having issues in sandbox mode.

The docs seem to suggest that url should work:

```
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/
```

thanks for any help ;)

Comment: The same error. I have just sent a request to support team, waiting for the answer...

Comment: Sandbox issues should now be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Have just received this response from the support team:

> We are already aware of the issue. Our engineers are working on it for a quick resolution.
> I will let you know once the issue will be resolved.
>
> Thank you in advance for you collaboration.

Comment: is it broken again!